# Logstash - match filename

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have two servers. The first one hosts elastic stack. Both servers have a file /var/log/commands.log which is configured in the same way and are being shipped with filebeat to logstash.

Using grok, I tried parsing the data into custom fields using this statement:

```
if [log][file][path] == "/var/log/commands.log" {
grok{
match => { "message" => "*some grok stuff*"
}
}
}
```

Problem is, even though on both servers the file is /var/log/commands.log & they're configured the same - it skips the if statement as if it's false.
I've noticed that if I ship the logs locally (without filebeat - just do input{file{input => "/var/log/commands.log}} ) it works for the local "/var/log/commands.log" file on that machine that hosts logstash.

For reference, this is the full .conf file for logstash: https://pastebin.com/1QbnAG7G

This is how elastic sees the file path: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuORi.png

Does anyone why it skips the "if" statement? How to make it filter by name.  Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you're using `=~` in your pastebin code. If that's the case, you'll be matching a regex. Is that what you meant to do?

If you're intending to use a regex, then you'd want something like this, probably:
`if [log][file][path] =~ /\/var\/log\/commands\.log/`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/nqGg9G/1